# R Shiny, how to use highcharts drilldown in shinyapp depending on selectinput widget result?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I am trying to create a drill down chart using highcharts package, the chart must be dependent on the selectinput results.

The current error is 
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

the expected or desired output is to get dynamic plot depending on the selected value.

```
library (shinyjs)
library (tidyr)
library (data.table)
library (highcharter)
library (dplyr)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shiny)



x <- c("Farm","Farm","Farm","City","City","City","Ocean","Ocean")
y <- c("Sheep","Sheep","Cow","Car","Bus","Bus","Boat","Boat")
z <- c("Bill","Tracy","Sandy","Bob","Carl","Newt","Fig","Tony")
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
b <- c(3,2,5,1,3,5,1,5)
c <- c(4,6,7,7,4,2,1,6)

xxxx <- data.frame(x, y, z, a, b, c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



header <- dashboardHeader()
body <- dashboardBody(
selectInput("selectid","Select a Measurement",choices=c("a","b","c"),selected = "a"),
 highchartOutput("Working"))
 sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

zzz<-reactive({
#browser

  select(xxxx,one_of(c("x", "y", "z", input$selectid)))})
output$Working <- renderHighchart({
summarized <- zzz() %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(!!sym(input$selectid)))
summarized <- arrange(summarized, desc(Quantity))

tibbled <- tibble(name = summarized$x, y = summarized$Quantity)



# This time, click handler is needed.

drilldownHandler <- 
  JS(
    "function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('ClickedInput', event.point.drilldown);}")
    installDrilldownReceiver <- JS("function() {
                         var chart = this;
                               Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('drilldown', function(message) {
                               var point = chart.get(message.point)
                               chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(point, message.series);
                               });
}")

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(events = list(load = installDrilldownReceiver, drilldown = drilldownHandler)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series(tibbled, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y, drilldown = name, id = name), color = "#E4551F") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE)
})
observeEvent(
#browser
input$ClickedInput, {
levels <- strsplit(input$ClickedInput, "_", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
resemblences <- c("x", "y", "z")
dataSubSet <- reactive({
  #browser()
  zzz()
})

for (i in 1:length(levels)) {

  dataSubSet() <- zzz()[zzz()[[resemblences[i]]] == levels[i],]

}
normalized <- data.frame(category = dataSubSet()[[resemblences[length(levels) + 1]]], amount = input$selectid)
summarized <- normalized %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(amount))
summarized <- arrange(summarized, desc(Quantity))
tibbled <- tibble(name = summarized$category, y = summarized$Quantity)
nextLevelCodes = lapply(tibbled$name, function(fac) {
  paste(c(levels, as.character(fac)), collapse = "_")
}) %>% unlist
tibbled$id = nextLevelCodes
if (length(levels) < length(resemblences) - 1) {
  tibbled$drilldown = nextLevelCodes
}
session$sendCustomMessage("drilldown", list(
      series = list(
        type = "column",
    name = paste(levels, sep = "_"),
    data = list_parse(tibbled)
  ),

point = input$ClickedInput

))
})  
output$trial <- renderText({input$ClickedInput})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```